# Wordpress Plugin Recommendation

Tags: wordpress

I'm rebuilding a site for an [artist collective](http://17thavenuestudios.org/_main/). The current site has each artist featured on a thumbnail on the landing page and each thumbnail links to a simple artist profile. The problem is it's all written in static html so when an artist comes or goes they have to do some formatting to incorporate them into the site. I'm trying to re-do the site so this can be managed via word press. Can anyone recommend a good plugin for my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Your purpose can be solved in just 3 steps without using any plugin.

1) Create on category in wp backend called "artices"

2) Create new post, Just have to use `setfeatureimage` option to set picture of artices and select "artices" category

3) Advantage will be you will be able to insert additional info for each artist with wordpress's default post editior.

4) Display all post with features images.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your experience with Wordpress but I would recommend [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) when you need to custom additional meta inside of Wordpress.